# Https - layout broken

Tags: layout, css, ssl, https

When I open the site using `https://mydomain.com` all layout (front/backend) is "broken" and appears inconsistent:

- The headers contains all js/css but they are loaded with `http://` protocol and the css rules are not applied

**My problem looks exactly like this:** https://demo.magentocommerce.com/

**EDIT:**
I have tested on my local installation ( same DB/CODE ) and it is working fine.

**EDIT 2**
After some investigation we found out that our FastCGI/Sbox is not setting HTTPS server variable when needed and that cause the wrong behavior on Magento

Comment: check your secure url settings.

Comment: those are ok `https://mydomain.com`

Comment: Maybe you have the setting on a level lower (website, store) where the setting is different? Or there is caching going on?

Comment: Really this is not the issue, I'm quite sure it is server config related problem

Comment: @Francesco make sure that you have a trailing slash in those fields

Comment: Are you using varnish or some kind of caching besides the standard Magento cache?

Comment: url in backend looks ok. I have compilation enabled, I have compiled again and refreshed cache

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution:**
The issue was generated by the server environment, it did not set [HTTPS] variable in the right way.

Adding this line in `index.php` restored the expected behavior

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && (443 == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'])) $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: See [this article](http://s.onas.si/vm8o) - you could do that more elegantly in your `.htaccess`. By using `SetEnvIf SERVER_PORT 443 HTTPS=on`

Comment: you are right, however 'SetEnv' and 'SetEnvIF' doesn't work on some CGI Env.

Comment: Then set the `fastcgi_param` accordingly then. Eg. for Nginx `fastcgi_param  HTTPS $https if_not_empty;`

Answer (score 6):

#### Your browser is probably blocking un-secure content

Some versions of recent browsers (FireFox/Chrome) will *reject* `HTTP` content when the page is served over `HTTPS`. This is to prevent insecure content being served alongside secure content.

So if you visit the homepage in Magento and specify `https://` in the URL, all the linked resources within the page source will still be `http://` - and the browser may reject loading that content to preserve security.

But if you've loaded the page once before, there's a good chance that some CSS/JS/Images may well already be in the browser cache, mitigating the requirement to fetch the resource remotely.

This can give the impression that it works on some machines and not on others. Where in reality - its not really working for anyone, its just that some users benefit from their historical browser cache.

Self-signed certificates can also produce this exact behaviour.

#### Magento won't use HTTPS on the Homepage by default

Magento doesn't want/need to serve content over `https://` unless either

1. The page warrants HTTPS (customer account, checkout etc.)
2. You changed the unsecure base url to be HTTPS regardless

Under normal situations, there simply isn't a requirement for the homepage to be served over HTTPS - and if your unsecure base url is just `http://` - then Magento will still continue to load un-secure resources.

So if you want HTTPS on your homepage, either change core code to dictate whether the area needs to be secure or not - or make the entire site HTTPS regardless.

#### Its normal, don't worry

Basically, what you are seeing is normal behaviour - on the front-end at least. Just because you *want* HTTPS on the homepage, doesn't mean Magento *will* serve everything to you with HTTPS.

Its more concerning what is happening with your back-end, but again, if you haven't actually enabled "Use Secure URLs in Admin" and defined a `https://` URL for the "Base Secure URL" - then again, what you see is normal.

If you want HTTPS, ensure you enable in the front-end/back-end as appropriate and set the "Base Secure URL" to suit.

Comment: I think the issue is related to Fastcgi/sbox: I have checked and it doens't set the variable Server variable HTTPS.

Comment: What I'm experiencing it is not the default magento behavior: as I wrote in the question it works well on my local installation

Comment: Unless you have set ALL your URLs to be HTTPS - Magento will NOT serve HTTPS content on the homepage. And your browser will potentially block that content. Take our own website as an example, https://www.sonassihosting.com/ - forcing HTTPS breaks the CSS and JS rendering in FireFox.

Comment: this just a test to debug the issue: that is why I'm opening the url direclty on https://.
On local it work on live not, the reason is the above comment

Comment: But you cannot test it with the homepage. Test a resource that actually _should_ be HTTPS, checkout/customer login etc. Not the homepage, **unlesss* you've changed the unsecure base URL to be `https://`

Comment: guys if you open the home page with 'https://' is should work. The fact that Magento redirect checkout to https is another story. Below the solution

Comment: *Unless* you've changed the unsecure base URL to be `https://` - the homepage elements will NOT be served securely. View the page source.

Comment: you just need to open it manually.