# Google indexing https for homepage - solutions?

Tags: indexing, css, ssl, javascript, https

It seems google has started indexing the secure url for my site's homepage - this has caused the CSS and JS links to break a la [Https - layout broken](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/896/https-layout-broken), but I'm not sure how to fix it, as the answer in that thread didn't explain what needed to be changed, and I wouldn't even know where to start with google

Does anyone know of a solution to either stop google indexing the secure homepage, or what to do to allow the CSS and JS files to have secure urls?

Comment: Put everything behind SSL. http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/ssl-everywhere-or-hsts/

Comment: Are there any cons to putting the whole site behind SSL?

Comment: people discussing that this costs more cpu, this is right on old hardware. Beside of this, google might rank https higher(?)

Comment: hmm interesting, unfortunately your blog post is a little out of my depth, do I need to understand all of it in order to implement this?

Comment: no, the blogpost is in the beginning about why SSL is important but the main point of the post is to use HSTS, which is a tecnique to avoid the first request to be http (just read the wikipedia article about HSTS). What you just have to do is set your secure and unsecure base_url to https://*

Answer (score 1):

What you just have to do to just serve everything via `HTTPS` is, to set your `secure` and `unsecure` `base_url` to `https://*`

Comment: Hey Fabian, Thanks so much, this has worked, although it has broken a few minor things, one of which is embed codes to youtube videos, of which we have quite a few! - do you know of any way to automatically redirect any http link to the https?

Comment: Instead of using http:// you should use // in your code, this is HTTP standard (or HTML?) and says: please use whatever protocol this site is using, like / for please us the base url. Beside of this, you can just throw a redirect into your htaccess (better htconf) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4083233/1480397

Comment: Do not forget to mark as this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey again Fabian, unfortunately this doesn't work as a long term solution - we have a 3rd party order/inventory management system and the api won't work with your solution :\

Comment: why that?! I hope your API connects via https, if not you send _ALL_ your business data unencrypted through the web!?

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your .htaccess page to get Google to un-index your homepage as secure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.your_domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The above will 301 redirect a user or Google that tries to land on your homepage securely to the non-secure version.

It may take Google a few weeks to correct its index, but the code above will fix the insecure mismatches.

Comment: This may mistakenly also try to redirect the cart/checkout/admin which *should* be https and therefore cause a redirect loop.

Comment: It shouldn't, as it matches only the root domain with "^$" in the rewriterule. It will not interfere with other URLs. We use this rewrite all the time for many clients' websites without any issues. It simply only redirects the homepage if it is accessed securely (which Firefox forces by default).